# properly using cursors in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to make output like this:

```
In the case of a valid employee or employees:
Enter value for sv_firstname: chris
Enter value for sv_lastname: miller
Employee ID: 41822 Description: Cashier Pay Rate: $11.63
Employee ID: 80809 Description: Butcher Pay Rate: $19.26

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR emp_cursor IS
  Select e.empid, j.description, j.payrate from 
  employee e, job j where j.jobcode = e.jobcode AND 
  lower(lastname) = lower(lname) and 
  lower(firstname) = lower(fname);
   fname employee.FIRSTNAME%TYPE:='&fname';
   lname employee.LASTNAME%TYPE:='&lname';
   emp employee.EMPID%TYPE;
   descript job.DESCRIPTION%TYPE;
   p_rate job.payrate%TYPE;

BEGIN 
  OPEN emp_cursor;

LOOP
  FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp,descript,p_rate;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname||' '||lname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Number: ' || emp);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Description: ' || descript);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pay Rate: ' || p_rate);      
  EXIT WHEN  emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  Close emp_cursor;      
END; 
/
```

this is the error im getting

Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 11:
PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
ORA-06550: line 3, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 15:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have now? You haven't shown any data, your current output, or what your issue is.

Comment: Try declaring `fname` and `lname` before using them in the cursor. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem at the moment is that you have the cursor declaration before the variables; it needs to be the other way around, And you have the exit in the wrong place.

This runs, at least:

```
DECLARE
  fname employee.FIRSTNAME%TYPE:='&fname';
  lname employee.LASTNAME%TYPE:='&lname';
  emp employee.EMPID%TYPE;
  descript job.DESCRIPTION%TYPE;
  p_rate job.payrate%TYPE;

  CURSOR emp_cursor IS
    Select e.empid, j.description, j.payrate from 
    employee e, job j where j.jobcode = e.jobcode AND 
    lower(lastname) = lower(lname) and 
    lower(firstname) = lower(fname);

BEGIN 
  OPEN emp_cursor;

  LOOP
    FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp,descript,p_rate;
    EXIT WHEN  emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname||' '||lname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Number: ' || emp);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Description: ' || descript);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pay Rate: ' || p_rate);      
  END LOOP;
  Close emp_cursor;      
END; 
/
```

It doesn't produce the output in the format you wanted but you should be able to play around with that now. You should also consider using ANSI join syntax instead of Oracle's old comma-separated syntax. And it might be simpler to use bind variables rather than substitution variables here.

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out thanks

```
DECLARE
    fname employee.FIRSTNAME%TYPE:='&fname';
    lname employee.LASTNAME%TYPE:='&lname';   
    emp employee.EMPID%TYPE;
    descript job.DESCRIPTION%TYPE;
    p_rate job.payrate%TYPE;   
  CURSOR emp_cursor IS
   Select e.empid, j.description, j.payrate from 
    employee e, job j where j.jobcode = e.jobcode AND
    lower(lastname) = lower(lname) and 
    lower(firstname) = lower(fname);

BEGIN 
  OPEN emp_cursor;

LOOP
  FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp,descript,p_rate;
  EXIT WHEN  emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Number: ' || emp);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Description: ' || descript);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pay Rate: ' || p_rate); 

  END LOOP;
   if emp_cursor%ROWCOUNT<1 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname||' '||lname||' does not exist');
  END IF;
  Close emp_cursor; 

END; 
/
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out; I took too long posting my answer *8-)